# A strange planar set and the Continuum Hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, euclidean-geometry, continuum-hypothesis

Call a number  *abnormal* if its decimal expansion doesn't feature every digit an infinite number of times.  Call a triangle in ${\Bbb R}^2$ *abnormal* if at least one of its angles spans an abnormal fraction of $2\pi$ radians.

Assuming the Continuum Hypothesis, by the obvious transfinite induction, one gets a set $M$ so small that no three of its points form an abnormal triangle, but so large that every point of ${\Bbb R}^2$ either falls in $M$ or else occurs as the midpoint of two points in $M$.

Does such an $M$ exist in ZFC?

Comment: Can't you just perform your recursion in length $\frak{c}$ rather than length $\omega_1$? This will avoid the need for CH.

Comment: Well say you're looking to make $p$ the midpoint of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  One strategy would involve focusing the search on a certain circle $O$ centered at $p$.  But then each pair of points already in $M$ eliminates $c$ points of $O$ from consideration.  If there are more than countably many such pairs, you can't make an appeal to probability theory, so what would you do?

Comment: Assume MA, of course! That's what you do. :)

Comment: Not something I feel comfortable doing in ZFC :)

Comment: May I confess my pedagogical motivation: to devise the most elementary sounding statement I could that depends on CH for its proof.

Comment: @David I have a candidate for that: $\mathrm{CH}$ holds if and only if the plane $\mathbb R^2$ can be covered by 3 clouds. (See [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0168007201000422/1-s2.0-S0168007201000422-main.pdf?_tid=spdf-478d05bb-1087-49c1-ac55-88828d9d0c59&acdnat=1519814635_2923911226027f6c4a8bcf5a231c4892).) With a little more work you can actually squeeze out a characterization of $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_n$ for all $n < \omega$ -- a result we rediscovered over lunch during least year's Arctic Set Theory Conference.

Comment: There is a mean called Davies trees which could enable you to remove CH. One reason in which usually we cannot go up beyond \aleph_1 when CH fails is that  we cannot get a countable elementary substructure at stage \omega_1 if of course a proof using countable elemenatry substructures exists. Now, everything here is definable and you may use elementary substructure in order to get M under CH. Now Davies tree gives you again a countable elementary substructure at level \omega_1. You can take a look at the following interesting paper. https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.06195